# How to make uislider like apple music

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

If you click on the status bar, the thumb gradually increase in size, and when you take your finger is reduced.

I tried:

```
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage.init(named: "dot"), for: .highlighted)
```

But size does not change smoothly when you remove your finger from the slider to the status bar fills up on the left edge of the control.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage.init(named: "dot"), for: .highlighted)
```

into this line:

```
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage.init(named: "dot"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: thank you for answer! So I wrote but it's not a decision that apple, you need an animated change control

Comment: see how it works in uislider apple music, I would also like!